# How to call QnA Maker on a waterfall dialog using C#?

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I am trying to call **QnA Maker** on a **waterfall dialog step**.

How do I call it from this `watterfall` step, do I need to set up QnA On the waterfall step, do I need to call **QnA** from a **LUIS intent**, what can I do?

[image: Code]

I need it to get the first result from the QnA using the step context from the previous question.

Can anyone help?

Code:

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> QnaAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var response = await qnaMaker.GetAnswersAsync(stepContext);

    // use answer found in qnaResults[0].answer
    return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text(response[0].Answer)}, cancellationToken);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you don't have `qnaMaker` defined in your code above, there. You can really call QnAMaker from anywhere, so long as you have a QnAMaker service defined somewhere.

I recommend following [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/49.qnamaker-all-features). It's fairly complex, but is the best example of using QnAMaker within a Waterfall Dialog.

I'll point out some pieces that you will find most useful:

1. [Create the QnAMaker service](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/49.qnamaker-all-features/BotServices.cs#L13)
2. Use [dependency injection](https://stackify.com/dependency-injection-c-sharp/) so that you can [access the BotServices from anywhere in the project](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/49.qnamaker-all-features/Startup.cs#L36)
3. [Add the services to the dialog's constructor](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/49.qnamaker-all-features/Dialog/QnAMakerBaseDialog.cs#L51)
4. [Call the QnAMaker service](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/49.qnamaker-all-features/Dialog/QnAMakerBaseDialog.cs#L129)

Again, that sample is fairly complex. If you need additional pointers, please update your question with the code that you've tried and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: Could someone please help me out on doing this using the python BotFramework SDK?. I have asked a new question for this as well - [Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65086558/how-do-i-switch-between-qnamaker-and-waterfall-dialogs-in-python-azure-botframew). Thanks a lot.